# Is making this question more general appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Prior to **answering** [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293414/where-are-the-fallout-4-screenshots-saved/293430#293430) about Fallout 4 screenshots, I searched the site for a more general "Steam game screenshot location" question but couldn't find one. Would it be appropriate to edit the title and tags of the question to make it apply to all steam games in general? Would it be better to ask and answers a more general question and mark the FO4 question as a dupe?

Comment: Neither.  Just ask the question.

Comment: "Neither" isn't compatible with the rest of your comment, @Frank. I think we failed to communicate somewhere. Which question do you think I should be asking?

Comment: It's a moot point in this case as it's actually off-topic due to the user wanting support for a [cracked copy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293414/where-are-the-fallout-4-screenshots-saved/293430#comment414497_293430) of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with StrixVaria - don't edit existing questions to make them more general.  If you feel that having a "Where can I find my Steam screenshots?" question is useful then go ahead and ask+answer it.  Let the community judge whether it is a duplicate, or other questions are a duplicate.

Regardless, I feel that this question is probably the one you are looking for:

[Where did my screenshots go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30051/where-did-my-screenshots-go)

The title of the question could probably do with a little tidy up to make it easier to find.  Other than that I think that this has enough in there to help people find the screenshots for most Steam games.

Answer (score 2):

Don't edit other questions to ask questions you want to know the answer to. Just ask your question on the site and we'll figure out any duplicate issues as they come up.

Having duplicates on the site isn't bad, and having your question closed as a duplicate isn't a bad thing and doesn't reflect poorly on you. If you made a good faith effort to search for the answer to your question, and couldn't find it, then your duplicate question may help someone in the same boat as you down the line find the right question.

As an answerer, your responsibility is only to answer the question as asked. Our site is not intended to nor should it become an encyclopedia of gaming knowledge. It's a Question and Answer site. In 99% of cases, people should ask questions as they run into practical issues during the course of playing games, and people should answer the questions asked to help people who have run into these difficulties.

Comment: Help me out here. How have I failed to communicate that I am not the one asking a question? I want to increase the utility of the question that I ANSWERED

Comment: Sorry, let me edit to address that as well.

Comment: @Dallium Essentially, if a question pertains to finding where Fallout 4's screenshots are located, this will be a much different question than asking where Steam stores screenshots. Steam stores screenshots in a ridiculously complicated manner, and only Fallout 4's screenshots are saved in "[steam directory]/userdata/[userID number]/760/remote/screenshots/377160".

Comment: @Kaizerwolf but MOST steam screenshots are stored in [steam directory]/usedata/[userID number]/760/remote/screenshots/[GameID], which is essentially the same answer

Comment: @Dallium Regardless, Strix is right; there's no reason to take a question like that and turn it into something more general. You might as well just ask a new question.